# Launchd Failing to Launch: "Failed to exec(3) for some weird reason"

Tags: macos, launchd

I have a very simple lanuchd task set to kick off a backup script at a certain time every day.

I can run the command perfectly from the command line without any problems, but the following system log errors occur when it is attempted to be started by lauchd

```
9/4/14 9:30:17.534 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[422]: (local.meviocorp.BSbackupScripts[1938]) Job failed to exec(3). Setting up event to tell us when to try again: 2: No such file or directory
9/4/14 9:30:17.534 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[422]: (local.meviocorp.BSbackupScripts[1938]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 2
9/4/14 9:30:17.535 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[422]: (local.meviocorp.BSbackupScripts) Job should be able to exec(3) now.
```

The plist is so simple I can't imagine that it is the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.meviocorp.BSbackupScripts</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>bs_production_backup.py</string>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>9</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>30</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

any thoughts on where to look next?

Comment: It can't find `bs_production_backup.py`.

Comment: what is the basis of that comment? bs_production_backup.py is in the PATH. I will re-run with the fully specified path and see if you are correct! Thanks